# Saving a csv with zeros after some decimal points but not others

Tags: csv, google-sheets

I've got my hands on a Google Spreadsheet that I'm trying to save as a .csv and analyse in R. The problem is that with some numbers the decimal place is not really a decimal place. For example some numbers are input like "21.10" but really mean "21 of one thing and 10 of another". Similarly some are input "4.1" which means "4 of that one thing and 1 other".

It seems like the person who created the file in Sheets just clicked the "increase decimal places" button on the values that really meant 10s, 20s etc.
So the display in the editor is fine, but when I save the csv "21.10 is automatically converted to "21.1".

Complicating things further there are other values in the file that do have an actual decimal interpretation.

Is there a quick way to fix this without having to go back and "Hand-edit" data myself?

Comment: I was able to get this sort of display for numeric values with a custom format of `"0 . 00"`, and for that situation coercing to text format and outputting as csv as described below succeeded. This really has nothing to do with R so edited the tag.

Answer (score 2):

I have found in the past that converting the columns to text will retain the values as you see them; it's possible you could also create a calculated column that contains what you need and then copy that into a new sheet as a text column.

Comment: Tested. Works for me.

Comment: Excellent, hopefully this will be a sufficient answer and work for Boris